# Window7 Path variable is not working

Tags: java, java-7

I have installed jre7 on Windows 7. The path to it is `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`. I have tried to set the path variable so that I can run java programs from the command line, but `javac` gives me this error:

```
javac is not recognized as external or internal command, operable program or batch file
```

How do I set the path variable so that this will work?

Comment: Did you restart after changing `%PATH%`, or at least log out and back in?

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to set upto `bin` in JDK not in JRE,jdk has  `javac`
2. Restart terminal after setting path

Answer (score 0):

the best thing you can do is to first set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable in `Control Panel\System and Security\System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables` to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
```

then add following line to path variable to

```
;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

always after editing path, restart terminal

**EDIT**

if you want to use `javac` you must set `JAVA_HOME` to `jdk`path not `jre`path

Comment: how would it make `javac` in path ?

Comment: Jigar is correct.  There's no javac in JRE.

Comment: yes. I just want to write the standard way of setting jre/jdk

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the jre directory but use the jdk compiler directory which inside its bin directory